# Append a link using ajax in django

Tags: html, ajax, django

I have read through the internet to find out the best solution to pass a django link in  ajax.
Bellow is a django template link to remove an object from a manytomany relationship  using ajax call.

```
<html>     
    {% for objects in allobjects %}
        <div class="products">
            {{objects.title}}
            <a data-href="{% url 'app:removeitem' slug=objects.slug %}" >Revomove</a>
        </div>
</html>
```

My  removeitem view

```
 def RemoveItem(request,slug):
     #calling the function which returns user cart object
     cart=Cart_object(request)
     product=Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
     RemoveItem=False
     if request.is_ajax():
         if request.user.is_authenticated:
             cartinstance=Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
             if cartinstance:
                 cartinstance.products.remove(product)
                 RemoveITem=True
     #converting the available products in user cart object to jason
     prod=[]
     for x in cart.products.all():
         prod.append({'title':x.tittle})
     data={'products':prod,"image":x.image.url}
     return JsonResponse(data)
```

url.py

```
url(r'^Remove_item/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)',views.RemoveItem,name='remove_item'),
```

here is my ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('a').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault()
     var this_=$(this)
     var dataUrl=this_.attr('data-href')
     $.ajax({
        url:dataUrl,
        method:"GET",
        data:{

         },
        success:function(data){
         var cartbody=$('.cartbody')
         $.each(data.products,function(index,value){
           cartbody.prepend("<tr> <td > <img src='"+value.image+"'>"+ value.title+ "</td>")
         }

         }

       })
       })
       })
```

When ajax refreshes the div with the current available products, I would like ajax to also return remove link url to each available products returned by ajax. Please i need help

Comment: Do you mean sending the currently clicked link's url as ajax data ?

Comment: Yes . So that the user can have a link to remove items, when page reloaded using ajax

Comment: When you click the link, the ajax hits the url and does the removal already. Why would you need to send the url ?

Comment: I want to send remove url, so that the users can keep on removing avialable products in the  cart .

Comment: But the "not removed" products are still there, with their link, as when you loaded the page. why do you need to update them through the ajax call? Anyway, the same way you add the image url to each product (which by the way is wrong because you access `x` outside the forloop) you can also add the delete url to each product.

Comment: Please can you give me an example on how i can create an ajax link of that view function in codes